Discord js Using guild. but this error happens Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'members')
So I was writing tje code as a test to implement some functionality.
when a user sends a user ID with a command, the bot have to check if the id is on the server or not, but this error occurs  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'members')
    if (command === "give") {
        message.channel.send('test');
        if (guild.members.cache.find(m => m.id === args)?.id) {
    // true
    message.channel.send('FOUND');
} else {
    // false
    message.channel.send('who is that');
}}

Is there a way to solve the problem or is there another way?

that implies guild is undefined - the code you've shown doesn't indicate otherwise

How do you define guild? Is the command being ran outside of a guild?

I think it is because you have not defined what guild is.
Try doing this way by replacing GUILD_ID with your guild, assuming args is a user id
if (command === "give") {
    message.channel.send('test');
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('GUILD_ID');
    if (guild.members.cache.has(args)) {
        // true
        message.channel.send('FOUND');
    } else {
        // false
        message.channel.send('who is that');
    }
}


I did but I meant, it says 'members' is not defined

@희민TV-HeeminTV
It means that guild is most likely undefined try doing console.log(guild) and see what it outputs, could you also send how you defined guild?
